# GIT pull, moved files locally

Tags: git, github, git-pull

I'm very new to git. And I was doing a git pull from a remote server. First, let me explain my situation.

I have two folders that I've set `app` and `app.my`. Both of this folders are within `myApps` folders.

I use `app` to `clone` my remote repository and is used for testing and production only. Whereas, the `app.my` I want to use `pull` for developing the current app. Because I feel that committing would be easier, according to what I understand, that is.

> Kindly take note, I use private keys to access my repository, and have added it to my `~/.bash_profile` . So, nothing is wrong there, I'm positive. I think.

In my terminal, I'm inside my `app.my` folder. When I use `git pull userID@url`,it successfully pulls my files. But instead of pulling all those files into my `app.my` folder, it pulls all the files to my `myApps`folder. I tried deleting those files LOCALLY, and redo-ing `git pull`. Naturally, it says everything is fine. When I enter `git status` it showed all my files are DELETED.

So, I tried `git reset --hard` All those files were restored, but into the `myApps` folder instead of the `app.my` folder.
Then I tried moving the files LOCALLY, and again entered `git status` to see what happens.

It says my files are deleted. But I understand that there is something wrong with the path that is set.

How do I make the files to be placed in my `apps.my` folder instead of the parent folder, `myApps`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well for me it looks like you have cloned the repository initialy into `myApps` some day. Just check out where your .git folder is located.

Comment: and how do i do that @ckruczek ? :(

Comment: Look for the .git repository. Likely in your current folder or folders above. Ir you are on windows you need to activate hidden files and folders

Comment: I'm on Mac. @ckruczek

Comment: Well than just open your terminal navigate to your myapp folder and make a ls -la. If the .git repo is not there. Look up the parent folder until you found it.